# Get first 3 children from a simplexml element

Tags: php, xml

my problem is such that I only need to download 3 from this xml file, and it is such that I do not need 10 but only 3 of them,

in place of that I get 10 I will only use 3 because I want the 3 latest news about what is in the file, therefore I hear about how I make it possible that I only download 3 files

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.odin.dk/RSS/RSS.aspx?beredskabsID=d1d94661-0f60-4e67-aeff-304d22199f8a");
    echo "<table id='alarm' cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Melding</th>";
    echo "<th>Tidspunkt</th>";
    echo "<th>Dato</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    foreach ($xml->children() as $child) {
        foreach ($child as $c) {
            if ($c->getname() == "item") {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $c->description . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $c->comments . "</td>";
                $days       = array("Mandag", "Tirsdag", "Onsdag", "Torsdag", "Fredag", "Lørdag", "Søndag");
                $months     = array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Maj", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec");
                $timestamp  = strtotime($c->pubDate);
                $dayInWeek  = $days[date('N', $timestamp)-1];
                $month      = $months[date('n', $timestamp)-1];
                $dayInMonth = date('d', $timestamp);
                $year       = date('Y', $timestamp);

                echo "<td>$dayInWeek $dayInMonth $month $year</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a combination of xpath, to select only the item nodes, and then array_slice to get just the first 3 then you can do this while removing your inner foreach:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.odin.dk/RSS/RSS.aspx?beredskabsID=d1d94661-0f60-4e67-aeff-304d22199f8a");
echo "<table id='alarm' cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Melding</th>";
echo "<th>Tidspunkt</th>";
echo "<th>Dato</th>";
echo "</tr>";
foreach (array_slice($xml->xpath('/rss/channel[1]/item'), 0, 3) as $c) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $c->description . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $c->comments . "</td>";
    $days       = array("Mandag", "Tirsdag", "Onsdag", "Torsdag", "Fredag", "Lørdag", "Søndag");
    $months     = array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Maj", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec");
    $timestamp  = strtotime($c->pubDate);
    $dayInWeek  = $days[date('N', $timestamp)-1];
    $month      = $months[date('n', $timestamp)-1];
    $dayInMonth = date('d', $timestamp);
    $year       = date('Y', $timestamp);

    echo "<td>$dayInWeek $dayInMonth $month $year</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a counter and if its 3 then break the loop.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($child as $c) {
    if ($c->getname() == "item") {
        // code
        if ($i == 3) break;
        // display code
        $i++ ;
    }
}
```

Comment: it does not work and I have put up the version that you have helped this with me,